# How to append checked input type="checkbox"

Tags: javascript, jquery, checked

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="courseBody">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-fundamentals" value="js-fundamentals" />
      <label>JS Fundamentals - January</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-advanced" value="js-advanced" />
      <label>JS Advanced - February</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-applications" value="js-applications" />
      <label>JS Applications - March</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-web" value="js-web" />
      <label>JS Web - April</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="educationForm">
    <label>Onsite</label>
    <input type="radio" name="educationForm" value="onsite" checked>
    <label>Online</label>
    <input type="radio" name="educationForm" value="online">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then i must to check one or more elements like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="js-fundamentals" value="js-fundamentals"/>
```

And then I have to append  with jQuery selected checkbox to, between `UL` tags:

```
<div id="myCourses">
  <h3>My Courses</h3>
  <div class="courseBody">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="courseFoot">
    <p>Cost: 0.00 BGN</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is there are two `div` elements with same class:

```
<div class="courseBody">
```

I want to append selected element only to second `div`, how? Please Help...

Some update:

There is a button in HTML code:

```
<div class="courseFoot">
  <button value="signMeUp">Sign me up</button>
</div>
```

When is clicked, selected element must be append to second `div`, here is JavaScript code:

```
function solve() {
  let $courseFundamentals = $('input[name="js-fundamentals"]');
  let $courseAdvanced = $('input[name="js-advanced"]');
  let $courseApplications = $('input[name="js-applications"]');
  let $courseWeb = $('input[name="js-web"]');
  let $divOne = $('.courseBody');
  let $ulOne = $('<ul>');
  let $divTwo = $('#myCourses');
  let $h = $('<h3>My Courses</h3>');
  let $divThree = $('.courseFoot');

  let onSiteCheck = $('input[value="onsite"]').prop("checked", true);
  let onLineCheck = $('input[value="online"]');

  let $button = $('button[value="signMeUp"]');

  $button.on('click', signMeUp);

  function signMeUp() {
    if ($courseFundamentals.is(':checked')) {
      let $li = $('<li>');
      $li.append($courseFundamentals.val());
      $ulOne.append($li);
      $divOne.append($ulOne);
      $h.append($divOne);
      $divTwo.append($divOne);
    }
    /*if ($courseAdvanced.is(':checked')) {
                let $li = $('<li>');
                $li.append($courseAdvanced.val());
                $ulOne.append($li);
                $divOne.append($ulOne);
                $h.append($divOne);
                $divTwo.append($h);
            }if ($courseApplications.is(':checked')) {
                let $li = $('<li>');
                $li.append($courseApplications.val());
                $ulOne.append($li);
                $divOne.append($ulOne);
                $h.append($divOne);
                $divTwo.append($h);
            }if ($courseWeb.is(':checked')) {
                let $li = $('<li>');
                $li.append($courseWeb.val());
                $ulOne.append($li);
                $divOne.append($ulOne);
                $h.append($divOne);
                $divTwo.append($h);
            }*/





  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? what is the error or what is not working? Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: If you want to select an individual element that shares classes with other elements, you can set it an id attribute. In this case, it could be something like `<div id='selected-courses' class='courseBody'>`.

Comment: Is the signMeUp button located nearer to the courseBody div you want?  You could then locate that div based on the location of your button.  Otherwise, why not just find the courseBody div that's located in the myCourses div?

Answer (score 0):

You could verify if any `checkbox` was checked, then save them into an array to in order to append it in the target that you want.

```
function getCheckedControls(jsCourses) {
  let result = [], len = jsCourses.length, element;
  for (let c = 0; c < len; c++) {
    element = jsCourses[c];
    if (element.checked) {
      result.push($(element).parent());
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  let jsCourses = $("input[type=\"checkbox\"]"),
    btnSignMeUp = $("button[value=\"signMeUp\"]"),
    myCourses = $("#myCourses");
  btnSignMeUp.on("click", signMeUp);

  function signMeUp() {
    let checkedCourses = getCheckedControls(jsCourses), len = checkedCourses.length, element;
    for (let c = 0; c < len; c++) {
      element = checkedCourses[c];
      $(myCourses.children()[1]).children()[0].append($(checkedCourses[c])[0]);
    }
  }

  function getCheckedControls(jsCourses) {
    let result = [], len = jsCourses.length, element;
    for (let c = 0; c < len; c++) {
      element = jsCourses[c];
      if (element.checked) {
        result.push($(element).parent());
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="courseBody">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-fundamentals" value="js-fundamentals" />
      <label>JS Fundamentals - January</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-advanced" value="js-advanced" />
      <label>JS Advanced - February</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-applications" value="js-applications" />
      <label>JS Applications - March</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="js-web" value="js-web" />
      <label>JS Web - April</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="educationForm">
    <label>Onsite</label>
    <input type="radio" name="educationForm" value="onsite" checked>
    <label>Online</label>
    <input type="radio" name="educationForm" value="online">
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="myCourses">
  <h3>My Courses</h3>
  <div class="courseBody">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="courseFoot">
    <p>Cost: 0.00 BGN</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="courseFoot">
  <button value="signMeUp">Sign me up</button>
</div>
```